# How does the Visual C++ compiler pass the this ptr to the called function?

Tags: c++, vtable, this-pointer

I'm learning C++ using Eckel's "Thinking in C++". It states the following:

- If a class contains virtual methods, a virtual function table is created for that class etc. The workings of the function table are explained roughly. (I know a vtable is not mandatory, but Visual C++ creates one.)
- The calling object is passed to the called function as an argument. (This might not be true for Visual C++ (or any compiler).) I'm trying to find out how VC++ passes the calling object to the function.

To test both points in Visual C++, I've created the following class (using Visual Studio 2010, WinXP Home 32bit):

ByteExaminer.h:

```
#pragma once
class ByteExaminer
{
public:
short b[2];
    ByteExaminer(void);
    virtual void f() const;
    virtual void g() const;
    void bruteFG();
};
```

ByteExaminer.cpp:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "ByteExaminer.h"

using namespace std;

ByteExaminer::ByteExaminer(void)
{
    b[0] = 25;
    b[1] = 26;
}

void ByteExaminer::f(void) const
{
    cout << "virtual f(); b[0]: " << hex << b[0] << endl;
}

void ByteExaminer::g(void) const
{
    cout << "virtual g(); b[1]: " << hex << b[1] << endl;
}

void ByteExaminer::bruteFG(void)
{
    int *mem = reinterpret_cast<int*>(this);
    void (*fg[])(ByteExaminer*) = { (void (*)(ByteExaminer*))(*((int *)*mem)), (void (*)(ByteExaminer*))(*((int *)(*mem + 4))) };
    fg[0](this);
    fg[1](this);
}
```

The navigation through the vtable in `bruteFG()` works - when I call `fg[0](this)`, `f()` is called. What does NOT work, however, is the passing of `this` to the function - meaning that `this->b[0]` is not printed correctly (garbage comes out instead. I'm actually lucky this doesn't produce a segfault).

So the actual output for

```
ByteExaminer be;
be.bruteFG();
```

is:

```
virtual f(); b[0]: 1307
virtual g(); b[1]: 0
```

So how should I proceed to get the correct result? How are the `this` pointers passed to functions in VC++?

(Nota bene: I'm NOT going to program this way seriously, ever. This is "for the lulz"; or for the learning experience. So don't try to convert me to proper C++ianity :))

Comment: Are you just curious how it works (in which chase DeadMG's answer should satisfy you), or are you looking for something like pointer-to-member operators (which are part of the C++ language) or  'delegates', for which there are several implementations (because pointer-to-member operators have limitations), including in Boost or TR1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Member functions in Visual Studio have a special calling convention, `__thiscall`, where `this` is passed in a special register. Which one, I don't recall, but MSDN will say. You will have to go down to assembler if you want to call a function pointer which is in  a vtable.

Of course, your code exhibits massively undefined behaviour- it's only OK to alias an object using a `char` or `unsigned char` pointer, and definitely not an `int` pointer- even ignoring the whole vtable assumptions thing.

Comment: oh. Thanks for the hint - googling __thiscall was actually enough. `this` is always passed in ecx (on x86 also). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8tkfbw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

OK using DeadMG's hint I've found a way without using assembler:

1) Remove the ByteExaminer* arg from the functions in the fg[] array
2) Add a function `void callfunc(void (*)());` to ByteExaminer:

```
void ByteExaminer::callfunc(void (*func)())
{
    func();
}
```

... this apparently works because func() is the first thing to be used in callfunc, so `ecx` is apparently not changed before. But this is a dirty trick (as you can see in the code above, I'm always on the hunt for clean code). I'm still looking for better ways.

Comment: I've been notified recently that answers should not be included in the original question...